# Whenever trying to clone a repo or pull, I am being prompted to enter my username and password for Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I am using powershell. I'm using HTTPS cloning. Is there a way to avoid this?

I tried creating a token but I am part of a group and not sure how that will affect the others in my group.

I tried cloning my repo with SSH and received this error:

git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Answer (score 0):

I *believe* this is due to running the command in different locations in your file system.

Comment: You mean for the SSH part?

Comment: Yes, are you running the SSH command in the same directory every time, or different directories?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something similar to the following, I had an issue where my clone was failing with a fatal error after a few successful clones in my pipeline:

`git clone --branch %GIT_BRANCH% http://%GIT_CI_USER%:%GIT_CI_PASS%@%GIT_REMOTE_URL% %DEST_REPO_DIR%`

The `%GIT_CI_USER%` and `%GIT_CI_PASS%` variables are defined as protected variables in the project CI/CD Settings. They are a user and either password or key/token, I'm not too sure since I inherited this configuration and the user is the prior maintainer.